# Is there a way to stop my Windows 7 laptop from connecting to the Wi-Fi if the ethernet cord is plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Essentially I want to have my wireless automatically connect to the router, but only if the ethernet cord is disconnected. If the ethernet cord is connected, I don't want it to automatically connect to Wi-Fi.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the order in which Windows searches for network services:

1. Go to Control Panel → Network and Sharing Center
2. On the left-hand side, click "Change adapter settings"
3. Go to Advanced → "Advanced Settings..." (if you cannot see the menu bar, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> to make it visible)
4. The top list is the order in which connections are used. They can be rearranged using the green arrows.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not provide this feature by default. You might have to use 3rd party software, like [Wireless AutoSwitch](http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops have this functionality built into the hardware, and it can be controlled in the BIOS/UEFI settings. For instance, on HP EliteBooks it's called "LAN/WLAN switching". So look around in your computer's BIOS/UEFI, or check the manual to see if it has this feature.