# How to automatically disconnect from a wireless network, when connected to the Internet over ethernet?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, macbook-pro

I have a Retina MacBook Pro, that connects to a wireless network at work for intra- and internet access. I also regularly plug in an ethernet cable to access the same network. In my Network preferences I've ordered the USB Ethernet connection *above* the Wi-Fi connection, so my computer should prefer the ethernet connection. However it still **connects** to the wireless network, burdening our wireless router for no reason.

How do I configure my Mac to automatically disconnect from the wireless network, when it's connected to the Internet over an ethernet connection?

Related:  [Is there a way to stop my Windows 7 laptop from connecting to the Wi-Fi if the ethernet cord is plugged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/513732/is-there-a-way-to-stop-my-windows-7-laptop-from-connecting-to-the-wi-fi-if-the-e)

Comment: Does the MAC BIOS / UEFI not have an option for this? On Dell its under power, HP I think its called auto WLAN/LAN but with Apple its probably in display or some other counter-intuitive place (sarcasm, yes... but only lightly)

Comment: Sounds like Macs use EFI, but I can't even tell how to get into the setup menu for it without downloading a program like rEFIt. I read a forum post somewhere about a key combination involving Opt, Cmd, F and O... O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to [this page](http://www.heatxsink.com/entry/turn-off-airport-when-ethernet-is-plugged-in-on-osx). A guy by the name of heatxsink made a pretty handy script that will toggle your wifi on or off depending on the status of your ethernet connection.

You can add your own growl notifications pretty easily if you want. Also make sure to follow every step precisely as the script relies on filenames and locations of the files.

Other options: You can try out [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/). It seems promising to fill your need for automation.